# Why is random variable defined in such way?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

As for the definition of [Random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition), I think we can derive a probability measure on $E$. Then why don't directly define random variable as a probability measure (triple) on $E$, which matches its name better: a variable on $E$, that is random.

Why bother defining an underlining probability triple in the first place?

Comment: Because you make it hard for yourself to define (non-independent) random variables later, for example.

Comment: @user10354138 Do you mean after one defines a r.v. $X$, she tries to define another r.v. that is not independent of $X$?

Comment: I mean something like: if you have $Y=g(X)$ later, then they live on different probability space etc.

Comment: Consider the sum and product of two dice rolls. They each induce a probability measure on the integers. Now consider the difference between the product and sum. Given only the induced probability measures, could you find the induced probability measure of this difference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the *distribution (measure)* of a random variable is an important concept. Let's think about standard cases of real valued random variables. Given a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb R$ (a distribution), we can say certain things and prove certain theorems about this distribution. However, *we have lost all information about where the distribution comes from*. There are a hellavalot of different r.v.s that can produce the same distribution measure.

A random variable $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ whose distribution is $\mu$ carries a lot more information and immediately more questions can be asked and answered; for instance, it's hard to sensibly combine or "compose" distributions but this is really easy with the function-al perspective. Random variables are still just functions and it's a very large theme in mathematics, that studying the functions on "spaces" gives you more information than just studying the spaces themselves.

Also, in practice, distributions - be they part of a theoretical, pure proof or a piece of applied mathematics - will arise from functions. Historically and intuitively we love the concept of random variables, of some mysterious hidden process that we want to understand; the distribution measure is something we can derive from that, but we can't go the other way. Why lose information if you can avoid it?